# Is there a way to use Filtrify that has outdated jquery with bootstrap that needs higher versions of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I really like the Filtrify plugin with the multiple search categories like on this link http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/movies.html by Luis. It is perfect for my project but I'm using bootstrap as a framework and this plugin uses version 1.7.1 of jquery and bootstrap needs 1.9.+.  Is there a way so I can use both or is not possible? If not, do you guys know of similar plugin that I can use ? I need to be able to search multiple items and filter content by those items.  My first try was to use the instafilta but then I can only search for one item at a time, unless I don't know how to configure it. 
So to be exact, the Filtrify demo that I posted is exactly what I need.

This is the content of my project. I want to be able to search for for example Javascript and C++ and filter the users that have that in their list.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntT2x.jpg

This is my first post so I hope this is specific enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What conflicts or errors exist when you try using the plugin with jQuery 1.9? Nothing in question insinuates that there is an actual problem

Comment: If I use the older version of jquery that is 1.7.1 I get error in console 

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher

And bootstrap navigation dropdown for example doesnt work :(

Comment: That doesn't answer question of using 1.9 with plugin

Comment: yeah sorry. If I use the 1.9 version I get erros on all the javascript files that filtify uses like Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined and doesn't work, but then bootstrap works again.

Comment: `$` is not defined is a problem with how you are using jQuery, it is not a version issue. Sounds like page is also using `noConflict()`. Please show some code and list of script includes in order they are included

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/B1HjPwk.jpg) this code works for plugin but not bootstrap. If I change the version to 1.11.2 bootstrap works but not the plugin

Comment: And I'm sorry! I must have change it when i got the error back there with the referenceError. So if i have the new version I get 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webkit' of undefined on filtrify.js 
and if i use the old version I get :
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher. That's all. Sorry for the confusion back there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at "http://isotope.metafizzy.co/". It has a filter function, too.

Comment: I did take a look at this isotope but it doesn't have a multiple search like the others do. Unless I can impliment it somehow with this ?

Comment: Yeah but imagine if the colors in this context were over 30 or 40. I would have to have 40 checkboxes and that's not really what I'm looking for :( I i appreciate the effort thou!

Answer (score 0):

filtrify.js line 99: change the if statment with this

```
field = this._order[f];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old problem, but I was able to fix the jQuery conflict of using newer jQuery with Filtrify by using method 1 on this page: https://www.sitepoint.com/fix-jquery-browser-function/